# Passing an Enum To a COM Library method using Jacob

Tags: java, com, activex, jacob

I instantiate a COM Object, then invoke a method.

```
ActiveXComponent comp = new ActiveXComponent("MyDll.MyClass");

String argument1 = "test1";
String argument2 = "test2";

Variant[] arguments = { new Variant(argument1), new Variant(argument2) };

comp.invoke("myMethod", arguments)
```

Assuming MyDll has a method called

```
myMethod(String s1, String s2)
```

it works fine.

Now, what if I have a Method

```
myMethod(String s1, ReturnDeletedModeEnum enum)
```

with an enum defined in MyDll?

I need to pass the enum to the method somehow, but I don't know how to access it.

I tried getting the Enum as ActiveXComponent,

```
new ActiveXComponent("MyDll.ReturnDeletedModeEnum");
```

which (not surprisingly) didn't work:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't get object clsid from progid
```

I tried finding some more documentation about Jacob, because there seem to be Enum-specific classes, but I haven't found any explanation on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same uncertainty when I needed to call a method with an Enummeration parameter.  I couldn't find much documentation - JACOB or otherwise.

I did stumble across a [helpful post on the subject](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s225/enumerations.htm) which says `the values ... correspond to internally stored numbers` and `An enumeration in VBA is always of data type Long`.

Armed with that and the [MS Documentation for my particular Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193596(v=office.14).aspx), I gave this a try ...

```
Dispatch.call(oDocuments, "Open", fileIn, ... ,  new Variant(1L));
```

And it worked!

I'm sure there's a way to get actual "Enumeration" data structures, but this was good enough for me.